# Add CustomAttribute to class and propagate it to its properties

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to define a CustomAttribute with class level and I would like this attribute is propagated to all the properties of the class.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute
{
}

[MyCustom]
public class MyClass
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int C { get; set; }
}
```

I would like the properties A, B and C have also MyCustomAttribute assigned. I know I can define the Attribute for each property. But I want to define the Attribute in the class level.

Is it possible?

Comment: In a word no. Attributes are attached to classes or properties. But you could look from the property to its containing class when looking for the metadata for the property. So it depends if you are in control of where the attribute metadata is being inspected/consumed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, but depending on how you're using the custom attribute, you could have it check the class which defines the property, I.E.

```
public static bool IsDefinedOnPropertyOrClass(PropertyInfo info, Type attributeType)
{
  return info.IsDefined(attributeType) || info.DeclaringType.IsDefined(attributeType);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I am getting the Type of the property as parameter. But I have not access to the PropertyInfo. I am getting only a Type.

Comment: If all you're getting is the property type, you wouldn't be able to see custom attributes on the property regardless of whether they could be propagated.